# Class 'Google_Service' not found

Tags: api, blogger

I am working on the Google + API blogger code. I have downloaded  this file 
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client
I have inserted my Google Developer codes in the right places I do believe.
I am getting this error 
 Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /home3/aundie/public_html/dandewebwonders.com/Blog/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Blogger.php on line 33
Any help for a new developer in training would be most helpful. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9):

Try to include `autoload.php` file as the first require statement. I got the same error and this solved it for me.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem as well. The solution is moving to php 5.3 or higher, as the Google API PHP client uses the newer class loading mechanism in php.

Comment: nop, here I am on PHP 5.3.3 and I am getting the same problem :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just as the following at the beginning of the code, the same as advised by Lamiaa El-morsy

require_once 'src/Google/autoload.php';

Answer (score 1):

On the GitHub page, they've explained the requirement.

[image: Requirements]

So, you must install the required library first, by doing the following command if you're using composer.

```
$ composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```